# Swift - load different Views inside one View

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiview

I am working on a `Wishlist-App` and I am stuck on a problem that needs a bit of explanation:

**Pictures for a better understanding:**

My Main Page (1st picture) contains a `CollectionView` where the user can add items ("different Wishlists") which then looks like the 2nd picture:

[image]    [image]

At the moment the user can click on the "Main Wishlist" which then looks like this:

[image]

The user can "add a wish" (tap on the + button at the bottom) which then get's added to the "Main Wishlist" `TableView`.

**Code:**

My "Main Wishlist" - `cell` is in its own custom class, all the other "Wishlists" the user can add ("TestList", "TestList2) are one class.

The `TableView` that appears after tapping the "Main-Wishlist"- `cell` is not another `ViewController`. Is is simply a `View` which I let appear/disappear with `view.transoform`.

**This is my "WishlistView" (3rd picture):**

```
let wishlistView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()

lazy var theTableView: WhishlistTableViewController = {
   let v = WhishlistTableViewController()
    v.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    v.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    v.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    v.view.layer.borderWidth = 7.0
    v.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

let dismissWishlistViewButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "dropdown"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideView), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()

let menueButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(named: "menueButton"), for: .normal)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menueButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()

let wishlistLabel: UILabel = {
    let v = UILabel()
    v.text = "Main Wishlist"
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 30)
    v.textColor = .white
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

let wishCounterLabel: UILabel = {
    let v = UILabel()
    v.text = "5 unerfüllte Wünsche"
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 12)
    v.textColor = .white
    v.font = v.font.withSize(12)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

let wishlistImage: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.image = UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

**and it appears after the user taps the "Main Wishlist" -`cell` like this:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           
   if indexPath.item == 0 {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainWishlistCell", for: indexPath) as! MainWishlistCell
    
    cell.wishlistTapCallback = {
        // let wishlistView appear
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.wishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
        // let welcomeText disappear
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.welcomeTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
    
    }
       return cell
   }
 
   else if indexPath.item <= theData.count {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell
    
       cell.testLabel.text = theData[indexPath.item - 1]
        cell.testImage.image = self.image
        cell.testImage.image = imageData[indexPath.item - 1]
        
       return cell
   }
 
   // past the end of the data count, so return an "Add Item" cell
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddItemCell", for: indexPath) as! AddItemCell

   // set the closure
   cell.tapCallback = {
    
    self.listNameTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
   
    // let newListView appear
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.blurrImage.alpha = 0.96
        self.blurrImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        self.newListView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
   }
   return cell
}
```

***Question:***

In the end each `cell` (Wishlist) should have it's on `View` (with its own `TableView` and according `UIImage` and `Label`. But how can I load a new `TableView` for each new "Wishlist" that get's created?

I am NOT looking for a specific code-answer here! I am quite new to this and I have no idea how I can realize this. So I would be very grateful if you could explain to me how I can proceed and what the basic ideas are to realize this task, thanks in advance :) Just let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Yes, you can have a tableView and other views inside a collectionview cell - at least that's how I interpret your question. See for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045681/custom-cell-with-uitableview-inside-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: no that's not my question. My problem is: I have a working TableView Class but it is specifically implemented (label, image,..)  for the "Main Wishlist". But I would like to use this `tableView` that I have in a dynamic way for all the other cells in my  `collectionView`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement another UItableViewController there, using maybe a container View. And the view that it will contain will be your TestList (UITableViewController)